# Error While running query to find count difference

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to find the difference between 2 counts from same view i.e - 
Difference between Total count and Distinct count from the same VIEW view_z_a_base.

FYI - The view structure is - 
TABLE **z_a** is created from the VIEW **view_z_a** which is created from VIEW **view_z_a_base**.

Query Being Executed -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) -(SELECT COUNT(*)FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
<schema>.vw_z_a_base))AS no_of_duplicates
FROM <schema>.vw_z_a_base;
```

#### EXPECTED RESULT -

Difference of the 2 counts -

```
?column?
0
```

#### ACTUAL RESULT -

ERROR MESSAGE _

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
SELECT COUNT(*) -(SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM <schema>.vw_z_a_base))
FROM <schema>.vw_z_a_base

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Not implemented
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Not implemented
  code:      1001
  context:   'value' - Ill formed PARAM_EXEC in expression
  query:     41412011
  location:  pg_utils.cpp:1710
  process:   padbmaster [pid=22726]
  -----------------------------------------------;
1 statement failed.
```

The same query works for Tables but not for views, why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error and it ended up having to do largely with typecasting in my case.  Included below b/c theres literally three google results for this error so hopefully it helps someone.  In your case I would suspect that it has to do with the `SELECT COUNT(*)FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM <schema>.vw_z_a_base)` element.  I think you may be taking unnecessary steps here, which could be returning something that SQL is having a hard time performing subtraction with.  You should be able to eliminate the nested select here, which also makes things easier to read.  Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINT *) as no_of_duplicates from <schema>.vw_z_a_base
```

Returning to my case, my code went from:

```
case when coalesce(allup_charges,0) > 156.04 then 1
```

to:

```
case when coalesce(allup_charges::numeric,0)>156.04 then 1
```

This resolved my issue.  I also found that mysqlworkbench was much less fussy with typecasting here than tableau.  If you continue to run into the issue just over-typecast and you should be fine?